# About num1 and num2 in python calculator

Tags: variables, python-3.x

Why this works if isn't there a variable which says the value of the num1 and num2 variables?
I mean, It shouldn't be necessary to add input to num1 and num2?
I am quite confused and I am very new at coding

{

```
#Returns the sum of num1 and num2

def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

#Returns the subtracting of num1 and num2

def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

#Returns the multiplying of num1 and num2

def mul(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

#Returns the dividing of num1 and num2

def div(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2



def main():
    operation = input("What do you want to do (+,-,*,/): ")
    if(operation != "+" and operation != "-" and operation != "*" and operation != "/"):
        #Invalid operation
        print("You must enter a valid operation")
    else:
        var1 = int(input("Enter num1: "))
        var2 = int(input("Enter num2: "))

        if(operation == "+"):
            print(add(var1, var2))

        elif(operation == "/"):
            print(div(var1, var2))

        elif(operation == "-"):
            print(sub(var1, var2))

        else:
            print(mul(var1, var2))

main()}
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Code that works isn't intended for StackOverflow, I recommend codereview (part of the stackexchange network) or another source for explanations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have input in your code

The two lines are:

```
var1 = int(input("Enter num1: "))
var2 = int(input("Enter num2: "))
```

Read those 2 documentation blocks on python built-ins

- input() : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input
- int() : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int

Then you need to understand how function calls work

The names you assign to the parameters of a function are only valid **inside** its declaration, and does not need to be the same on all your code.

```
def my_function(fn_variable_name):
    return fn_variable_name + 1

# calling directly
print my_function(1) # outputs 2

# calling with variable
another_variable_name = 45
print my_function(another_variable_name) # outputs 46

# Storing result in variable
yet_another_variable_name = my_function(32)
print yet_another_variable_name # outputs 33

# Combining the 2
var_1 = 23
var_2 = my_function(var_1)
print var_1 # outputs 23
print var_2 # outputs 24
```

Comment: Yeah I know it has but it isn't the num1 or num2 variable

Comment: Pretty confusing but I will keep trying.... Sometimes I think that I will not get into coding.